# Pull parts of a column containing stings and creating dictionaries upon which values can be pulled based on common keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dictionary

I have a df that contains strings with multiple data that I want to parse and store as a dictionary. I would like to store `PubMed Identifier` as a `pmid` key and thew following digits as its values, `Embase` as `euid` and the following digits, `NCT` as `trialid` and the following number (no space), and disregard the numbers on there own or disregard `PubMed Identifier/Embase` without trailing/associated digits.

```
data = {"ORN": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "EN": ["PubMed Identifier 27955689", "PubMed Identifier 8010359Embase  24208639", "PubMed Identifier 12237786Embase  35148801", "PubMed Identifier NCT02360007 12537613"]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

    ORN EN
0   1   PubMed Identifier 27955689
1   2   PubMed Identifier 8010359Embase 24208639
2   3   PubMed Identifier 12237786Embase 35148801
3   4   PubMed Identifier NCT02360007 12537613


desired_df

    ORN EN
0   1   {"pmid": 27955689}
1   2   {"pmid":  8010359, "euid": 24208639}
2   3   {"pmid": 12237786, "euid": 35148801}
3   4   {"trialid": 02360007}
```

I can't understand what I should do wrt best approach. My idea of splitting the string across columns with `.split(expand=True)` and then reordering the columns and then merging back using a `to_dict()` is the best I can think of but any better suggestions would be great. String manipulations is something I need improving at.

Comment: sorry - having a hard time following what you're trying to do. Are you trying to construct multiple DataFrames, splitting row-wise based on whether 'Embase' or 'NCT' are in the second column? or are you trying to parse the values in the second column, splitting the 'Embase' and/or 'NCT' numbers into new columns? If you could show us what you want to happen with your example that would be really helpful. Keep in mind we don't know this dataset/field so the only things we can help with are the things you walk us through :)

Comment: @MichaelDelgado The latter, want to parse the values in the second column `EN` and return the results now shown in `desired_df`, thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't ORN 4 have a pmid?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, unfortunately this happens, no explanation as to why. This is what I get from my search queries on these bibliographic databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping dictionary, then construct a regular expression pattern in order to find all the key value pairs from each row, then remap the key-value pairs to dict

```
d = {'PubMed Identifier': 'pmid',
     'Embase': 'emid', 'NCT': 'trialid'}

pat = fr'({"|".join(d)})\s*(\d+)'
df['EN'].str.findall(pat).map(lambda l: {d[k]: v for k, v in l})
```

---

```
0                        {'pmid': '27955689'}
1     {'pmid': '8010359', 'emid': '24208639'}
2    {'pmid': '12237786', 'emid': '35148801'}
3                     {'trialid': '02360007'}
Name: EN, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the data with [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

Build dict with [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) + [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

1. Extract the data with [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df_extract = df['EN'].str.extract(r'PubMed Identifier\s*(?:(?P<pmid>\d+)(?:Embase\s*(?P<euid>\d+))?)|NCT(?P<trialid>\d+)')
```

or, use:

```
df_extract = df['EN'].str.extract(r'PubMed Identifier\s*(?P<pmid>\d+)?\s*(?:Embase\s*(?P<euid>\d+))?(?:NCT\s*(?P<trialid>\d+))?')
```

Result:

```
print(df_extract)


       pmid      euid   trialid
0  27955689       NaN       NaN
1   8010359  24208639       NaN
2  12237786  35148801       NaN
3       NaN       NaN  02360007
```

2. Build dict with [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) + [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df_extract.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict(), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
0                        {'pmid': '27955689'}
1     {'pmid': '8010359', 'euid': '24208639'}
2    {'pmid': '12237786', 'euid': '35148801'}
3                     {'trialid': '02360007'}
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df['EN'].str.extract('PubMed Identifier +(?P<pmid>\d+)|NCT(?P<trialid>\d+)|Embase +(?P<euid>[^ ]+)')
```

output:

```
       pmid   trialid euid
0  27955689       NaN  NaN
1   8010359       NaN  NaN
2  12237786       NaN  NaN
3       NaN  02360007  NaN
```

To have as dict, add `.T.to_dict()`:

```
df['EN'].str.extract('(?=PubMed Identifier\s+(?P<pmid>[^ ]+\d+))?|(?=Embase\s+(?P<euid>\d+))?').T.to_dict()
```

output:

```
{0: {'pmid': '27955689', 'euid': nan},
 1: {'pmid': '8010359', 'euid': nan},
 2: {'pmid': '12237786', 'euid': nan},
 3: {'pmid': 'NCT02360007', 'euid': nan}}
```

Comment: This is close but not quite there wrt to output, I must get to looking at reg expressions and use the `.extract()` method. This looks super helpful, thanks.